# MySQL stored procedure timeout

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stored procedure when I call it, it will time out.

The stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `DeleteAttachmentsByIDs`(IN p_ids nvarchar(1024), IN p_modifiedBy varchar(100), IN p_modifiedDate datetime)
BEGIN
    CALL splitter(p_ids, ',');
    update attachments set
    `IsDeleted` = 1
    , `ModifiedBy` = p_modifiedBy
    , `ModifiedDate` = p_modifiedDate
    where 
    id in (select * from splitResults);
END
```

I call it with this code:

```
CALL`DeleteAttachmentsByIDs`('12479,12480,12481', 'admin', '2019-04-03 09:38:50.072608')
```

I tried to change the stored procedure to

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `DeleteAttachmentsByIDs`(IN p_ids nvarchar(1024), IN p_modifiedBy varchar(100), IN p_modifiedDate datetime)
BEGIN
    CALL splitter(p_ids, ',');
    select * from splitResults;
END
```

it will return the result quickly as follows

```
'12479'
'12480'
'12481'
```

And when I try to run it manually as follows, it also runs quickly

```
update attachments set
    `IsDeleted` = 1
    , `ModifiedBy` = 'admin'
    , `ModifiedDate` =  '2019-04-03 09:38:50.072608'
    where 
    id in (12479,12480,12481);
```

So I don't understand what happened in this stored procedure that makes it run so slowly and how I can improve it?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `DeleteAttachmentsByIDs`(IN p_ids nvarchar(1024), IN p_modifiedBy varchar(100), IN p_modifiedDate datetime)
BEGIN
    CALL splitter(p_ids, ',');
    update attachments set
    `IsDeleted` = 1
    , `ModifiedBy` = p_modifiedBy
    , `ModifiedDate` = p_modifiedDate
    where 
    id in (select * from splitResults);
END
```

Here is the splitter function which create the splitResults

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `splitter`(x varchar(255), delim varchar(12))
BEGIN
SET @Valcount = substrCount(x,delim)+1;
SET @v1=0;
drop table if exists splitResults;
create temporary
table splitResults (split_value varchar(255));
WHILE (@v1 < @Valcount) DO
set @val = stringSplit(x,delim,@v1+1);
INSERT INTO splitResults (split_value) VALUES (@val);
SET @v1 = @v1 + 1;
END WHILE;
END
```

I add explain to the stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `DeleteAttachmentsByIDs`(IN p_ids nvarchar(1024), IN p_modifiedBy varchar(100), IN p_modifiedDate datetime)
BEGIN
    CALL splitter(p_ids, ',');
    explain update attachments set
    `IsDeleted` = 1
    , `ModifiedBy` = p_modifiedBy
    , `ModifiedDate` = p_modifiedDate
    where 
    id in (select * from splitResults);
END
```

And here is the execution plan result

```
 id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, UPDATE, attachments, , index, , PRIMARY, 4, , 12301, 100.00, Using where
2, DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, splitResults, , ALL, , , , , 3, 33.33, Using where
```

Comment: This usually means parameter sniffing is hurting your procedure, for starters. Is attachments a table with many records and columns, and a clustered index on id? That would mean an index lookup you run the where id in (hard-coded ids), and an expensive table scan (or several) for the parameterized procedure.

Comment: `WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM splitResults)` will cause table scan and can be very slow on large table. While `WHERE id IN (12479,12480,12481)` is fast because IN works well with constant. Try to run with EXPLAIN UPDATE if you use MySQL 5.6 or newer or `EXPLAIN SELECT isDELETED FROM attachments WHERE IN (SELECT * from splitResults)` on MySQL 5.5 or less

Comment: @dylanthelion attachments table have 12481 records and not id is the primary key.

Comment: On a table that small, it's probably more than parameter sniffing, then. It could theoretically be a combination of things. For instance, it looks like you're passing in int id as a varchar . If you compare with mismatched types like that, you are preventing any indexes from being used, which is a huge performance killer, but again, it seems unlikely to cause a timeout on such a small table, unless your limit is low. If you can get an execution plan, please post it, and I'll try and help tomorrow. If not, it looks like @ZamronyP.Juhara has some MySQL experience (TSQL is more my bag).

Comment: It seems update do a full table scan. How can I improve the query?

Comment: Maybe you can try UPDATE with JOIN, e.g. `UPDATE attachments A JOIN splitResults SR ON A.id=SR.splitValue SET ...` or maybe replace WHERE id IN (subquery) with EXISTS as explained in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara. It works. Thanks so much.